# How to fade out div slowly, update content, and then fade in div slowly, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, callback, fadein, fadeout

I have a `div` I want to fade out, update its content, and then fade back in. So far I have tried:

```
$('#myDivID').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#myDivID').replaceWith("<div id='myDivID'>" + content + "</div>");
    $('#myDivID').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

What happens is that the fade out completes and calls the anonymous callback. So far, so good.

The `div`'s content is replaced correctly, but the `fadeIn()` effect is immediate — no smooth transition, just a quick, snappy jump to the updated `div`.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I've posted 2 solutions that work. Cheers

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should do it this way (**this works, is tested code**):

```
$('#myDivID').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#myDivID').html(content);
    $('#myDivID').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Your code wasn't working because the new created div is instantly visible. Another solution is to add a `display:none` like the following:

```
   $('#myDivID').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $('#myDivID').replaceWith("<div id='myDivID' style='display:none'>" + content + "</div>");
      $('#myDivID').fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

Hope this helps
Cheers

Comment: I like the `html()` call, much cleaner code. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

use SetTimeOut

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#myDivID').fadeIn('slow'); }, 5000);
```

this works

jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/3XYE6/1/

```
$('#doit').click(function(){
    $('#myDivID').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#myDivID').html('New content in MyDiv ('+Math.random()+')')
        setTimeout(function() { $('#myDivID').fadeIn('slow'); }, 5000);
    });    
})
```

Answer (score 2):

this should do it!

http://jsfiddle.net/3XYE6/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
$('#myDivID').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#myDivID').replaceWith("<div id='myDivID'>" + content + "</div>")
    $('#myDivID').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn('slow'); 
});
```

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/PgcTZ/

I've put the hide before the delay to make the animation work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and it didn't work, though.

Comment: @Alex , as i suggested try setTimeOut , i can wait for 5 seconds..you can change the time

Comment: Yeah I just tested it on jsfiddle. Edited code, which works. Not sure if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use replaceWith the content will be visible that is why there is no smooth transition.

First hiding the div and then calling fadeIn will give smooth transition.

```
$('#myDivID').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#myDivID').replaceWith("<div id='myDivID' style='display:none'>" + content + "</div>");
    $('#myDivID').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/X3cnT/

```
$('#myDivID').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#myDivID').html("all this text");
        $('#myDivID').fadeIn('slow');
});
```