# chain jQuery's actions one after the other with delays

Tags: jquery, css

I builted a web with jQuery animations, but when I tested it on mobile devices grrrr.. Now I am trying to make as much as possible with CSS as I did not know how terribly bad works this on mobile devices.

I am trying to fade out and in some elements, adding the CSS classes `.easeOuts` for fading out, and `.easeIns` for fading in:

```
.easeIns{
   opacity:1;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;   
}

.easeOuts{
   opacity:0;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;   
}
```

I tried fading an element out:

```
$('.sectionTitle').addClass('easeOuts');
```

And works great making a linear fading out, but when trying to keep on programming this element's suposed actions (fading out, changing content while invisible and fading in again) it just does not apply the fade out and in effects, changing just content without respecting any order:

```
$('.sectionTitle').addClass('easeOuts').delay(100).html("hola").removeClass('easeOuts').addClass('easeIns');
```

How can I create a chain to respect action's orders and delays between them? Is this the correct way to animate elements with CSS?

Comment: Fade it with jquery `.fadeOut(500)` and do the rest on the complete function of the fadeout http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fade out div slowly, update content, and then fade in div slowly, using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879899/how-to-fade-out-div-slowly-update-content-and-then-fade-in-div-slowly-using-j)

Comment: I am trying to avoid jquery animations and effect as Ive tested my site on mobvile devices and all animated by jquery was really crappy. I do know how to fade out on jQuery, but does this method react as other animations on jquery? (looking bad, not fluid and loss of quality on mobile devices).

Comment: `.delay()` only affects animation queues. `.html()` `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` ignores those delays

Comment: You'd probably be best going down the route of using `setTimeout` in order to delay your changes

Comment: @Biomehanika if you don't want to use jquery fadeout then you probably need to use setTimeout because delay only works on animation or you can do `$('.sectionTitle').fadeIn(0).delay(100)` and do `$('.sectionTitle').addClass('easeOuts')` on the next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example using `setTimeout` to achieve what you're after!

```
$('.sectionTitle').addClass('easeOuts');
setTimeout(function(){ $('.sectionTitle').html("hola").removeClass('easeOuts').addClass('easeIns'); }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the effects specified in JQuery, use Callback Functions. These functions can be called once the current segment is complete.

For eg, defunethe function to be executed after the action is complete

```
function complete() {
$( "<div>" ).text( this.id ).appendTo( "#log" );
}
```

And Call the effect as

```
$( "#box1" ).fadeOut( 1600, "linear", complete );
```

This will fade the element and once it is done, will call `complete()`

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying NOT to use fade in/out/animations with jQuery as it looks really bad from mopbile devices....

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to timeout you can try the following

```
$('.sectionTitle').fadeIn(0).delay(100).html("hola").removeClass('easeOuts').addClass('easeIns');
$('.sectionTitle').addClass('easeOuts');
```